# Error:(25, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@string/app_id')

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I got this errors each time I wanna clean, rebuild project or build APK

Gradle tasks [:android:generateDebugSources, :android:generateDebugTestSources]
C:\Users\Abdel\Desktop\martianrun-master\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(25, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@string/app_id').
Error:(28, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@string/app_id').
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\Abdel\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\Abdel\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar -M C:\Users\Abdel\Desktop\martianrun-master\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Abdel\Desktop\martianrun-master\android\build\intermediates\res\debug -A C:\Users\Abdel\Desktop\martianrun-master\android\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\Abdel\Desktop\martianrun-master\android\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\Abdel\Desktop\martianrun-master\android\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.doragames.adventure.android -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Users\Abdel\Desktop\martianrun-master\android\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
>   Error Code:
>       1
>   Output:
>       C:\Users\Abdel\Desktop\martianrun-master\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:23: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@string/app_id').
>       C:\Users\Abdel\Desktop\martianrun-master\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:26: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@string/app_id').
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 10.424 secs
>   Information:3 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.gamesTex.adventure.MainApplication"
android:installLocation="auto"
android:versionCode="21"
android:versionName="21.1.2" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />

<application
    android:name="com.gamesTex.adventure.MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
        android:resource="@xml/app_tracker_config" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.gamesTex.adventure.android.AndroidLauncher"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

my styles.xml

```
<style name="GdxTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

my strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--
~ Copyright (c) 2014. William Mora
~
~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
~
~     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
~
~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
~ limitations under the License.
-->

<resources>

<string name="app_name">Martian Run!</string>

<!-- GameHelper strings -->
<string name="gamehelper_sign_in_failed">Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection and try again.</string>
<string name="gamehelper_app_misconfigured">The application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name and signing certificate match the client ID created in Developer Console. Also, if the application is not yet published, check that the account you are trying to sign in with is listed as a tester account. See logs for more information.</string>
<string name="gamehelper_license_failed">License check failed.</string>
<string name="gamehelper_unknown_error">Unknown error.</string>
<string name="auth_client_needs_enabling_title"></string>
<string name="auth_client_needs_installation_title"></string>
<string name="auth_client_needs_update_title"></string>
<string name="auth_client_play_services_err_notification_msg"></string>
<string name="auth_client_requested_by_msg"></string>
<string name="auth_client_using_bad_version_title"></string>
</resources>
```

Comment: You may show us the xml file to check it. The problem is obviously because the `@string/app_id` is missing or it place in some where your program can not found

Comment: it seems you didn't define a string named `app_id` in your `strings.xml`

Comment: Did you by any chance accidentally rename `app_name` to `app_id` in the manifest?

Comment: I have been edited my question guys